# Database access best practices with VB.NET (VS 2012)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a questions for those who work with Visual Studio.

I am user of the good old VB 6.0.

Now I decide to start learning Visual Basic 2012.
Whats the best way to work with databases, but with access file.

I created a database and successfully connect with my application. I used the listview to list my records. But I can see a lot of different things. Text **change** event is not the same. My sql is not working with the LIKE statement like it was working at VB 6.

I used this method (code) and its working...but I want to know whats the best way, cuz it is far more different from VB6.

```
Dim con As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim dr As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\GigaC\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test_data\emp.accdb")

con.Open()

sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM contacts "
cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlStr, con)

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If dr.HasRows = True Then
   While dr.Read
     Dim X As ListViewItem
      X = List.Items.Add(dr(0))
      X.SubItems.Add(dr(1))
      X.SubItems.Add(dr(2))
    End While
 End If

 con.Close()
```

But code like

`sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE cname LIKE '" & txtName.Text & "*'"`
is not working. At my old VB6 I used to do that kind of search. With text change and this line of SQL to search the database and list the records.

Tell me the best way to work with databases and If you have some lessons online. Thank you, greetings

Comment: String concatenation to build queries is very dangerous - it leaves you wide open to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries (these will also be more efficient on the database side). As for the rest, the question is far, far too broad. There are *many* blog posts, articles, HOW-TOs and tutorials on database access with .NET applications available with a few simple Google searches.

Comment: I know and I am too sorry about that. But like I said, its my first time to work with this. I looked up for tutorials but somehow the only answers I get its the MSDN and I hate them :D

Comment: Learn how to use TechNet & MSDN - they really do have some of the best documentation around on this stuff. For example, [this tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301075) which includes how to use a parameterized queries instead of plain strings.